# How to scale my image from the middle in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

I want to scale my img from the middle. Right now it's starting from top left. This is my code :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").animate({
        height: '+=100%',
        width: '+=100%'
    });

});
```

```css
#logoblock
{
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
#logo
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logoblock">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: try this ‘.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
.logo img {
  width: 50%;
}‘

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript to do this. You can just use CSS animations, like this:

```css
#logoblock{
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

#logo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
}

#logo img {
  -webkit-animation: scaleImage 1s both;
          animation: scaleImage 1s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleImage {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes scaleImage {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logoblock">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a way to set a delay to that?

Comment: Of course, you can use the _animation-delay_ property. `#logo img {
          animation: scaleImage 1s both 2s;
}` With this the animation starts after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to change `CSS` and just want to alter the `jQuery`, you can do this

`CSS`:

```
#logo img { 
     -webkit-transform: scale(0) 
     -moz-transform: scale(0); 
     -ms-transform: scale(0); 
     -o-transform: scale(0);
        transform:scale(0);
     -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease; 
     -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease; 
     -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease; 
     -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
 }
```

`jQuery`:

```
    var val = 1;
    $('img').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        '-o-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        'transform': 'scale(' + val + ')'
    });
```

And by changing the `transition-duration` you can increase/decrease the delay for scaling.

Here I've also created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/8ekt0nvs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add additional animation direction: from initial center position (`left: 50%`, `top: 50%`) to `left: 0` and `top: 0`. Maybe like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").animate({
        height: '+=100%',
        width: '+=100%',
        left: '0',
        top: '0'
    });
});
```

```css
#logoblock {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logoblock">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code **.thumb { display: inline-block;    width: 200px;    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;    border: 3px solid #c99;    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;}**